# Can't get page content with curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the content of a webpage using curl, but i', getting an empty response. After checking the headers i've noticed that remote server returns 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily'

Of course, the same url in browser returns the page.

Why is this happening? Maybe remote server can understand that this is a curl request and has some limitations? Any ideas on how i could get the page content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option on:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect option (`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)`) from the answer of mudasobwa, is not fixing the problem, the server might also be blocking requests not from “normal” user agents. You could mimic user agent strings in curl with this option (example):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 " );
```

You could even add random user agents of browsers from a list like that one: http://www.vwp-online.de/ua.php?ua_type=browser